# Как сделать пробел при выборке строк из таблицы

Tags: php, mysql

У меня есть большая таблица с сотрудниками. В этой таблице есть поле "year" (год рождения).
С помощью цикла foreach я формирую на странице в столбик список всех строк из этой таблицы.

```
<span><?=$people['id'].': '.$people['name'].' '.$people['family'].', '.$peolpe['age'].' лет. Год рождения: '.$people['year'].'.';?></span> <br>
```

Но как сделать, чтобы после людей, родившихся в определенном году, шел пробел? Примерно так:

```
Иван Петров: 30 лет. Год рождения - 1990;
Петр Иванов: 30 лет. Год рождения - 1990;
Марья Петрова: 30 лет. Год рождения - 1990;

Иван Петров: 29 лет. Год рождения - 1991;
Петр Иванов: 29 лет. Год рождения - 1991;
Марья Петрова: 29 лет. Год рождения - 1991;
```

Comment: Запоминаете в переменной год, который был у строки. В начале следующей итерации цикла сверяете год с текущей записью и если не совпал выводите пустую строку (<br>)

Comment: Спасибо, получилось.

Answer (score 1):

С примера видно что Вы не используете шаблонизатор, и скорее всего проблема с выводом данных. Прочтите вот это https://www.php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php и тогда вы сможете подправить ваш код так, что бы по указанному диапазону дат выводился еще один `<br>`

Примерный код:

```
$collection = [
    [
        'name' => 'test',
        'year' => 1990,
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'test2',
        'year' => 1991,
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'test3',
        'year' => 1992,
    ],
];
?>

 <?php foreach ($collection as $people): ?>
    <span><?="Имя: {$people['name']} | Год рождения: {$people['year']}"?></span><br>
    <?php if ($people['year'] >= 1991 && $people['year'] < 1992): ?>
        <br>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```